# Insert into MySQL doesn't work when i'm using reference to another class in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Why is The following insertion doesn't work?

```
     $sql="INSERT INTO users (user, name, last, email) VALUES 
     ('$_subscriber->getUser()','$_subscriber->getName()',
     '$_subscriber->getSurname()','$_subscriber->getEmail()')";
```

But when I use it like that it does:

```
$user = $_subscriber->getUser();
$name = $_subscriber->getName();
$last = $_subscriber->getSurname();
$email = $_subscriber->getEmail();

$sql="INSERT INTO users (user, name, last, email) VALUES 
            ('$user','$name','$last','$email')";
```

What I did wring in the first try I don't want to use my workaround.

Comment: Echo out the SQL you're generating. PHP isn't interpolating the values correctly in the first one. You need to escape them inside the string, so PHP can parse it correctly - `'{$_subscriber->getUser()}'` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `{}` around values

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO users (user, name, last, email) VALUES 
 ('{$_subscriber->getUser()}','{$_subscriber->getName()}',
 '{$_subscriber->getSurname()}','{$_subscriber->getEmail()}')";
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you can't directly use object notation in a string like that.

```
"This $will->not() work"

"{$But->this()} will"
```

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: FGITW, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO users (user, name, last, email) VALUES 
     ('".$_subscriber->getUser()."','".$_subscriber->getName()."',
     '".$_subscriber->getSurname()."','".$_subscriber->getEmail()."')";
```